# How to invoke a bean method in Apache Blueprint?

Tags: java, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I have the following java classes

```
public class SecondClass
{
    //...
}

public class MyClass
{
    public void doSomething(SecondClass secondClass)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

In blueprint I have something like the following

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <bean id="secondClass" class="foo.bar.SecondClass" />

    <bean id="myClass" class="foo.bar.MyClass" />

    <!-- How do I invoke myClass.doSomething(secondClass) ??? -->

</blueprint>
```

Someone knows how to call myClass.doSomething(secondClass) from inside Blueprint?

Comment: Blueprint is used for dependency injection, not for executing code so I don't really understand what you mean be invoking the myClass.doSomething method from within blueprint. Could you please clarify a bit what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
I know it is not usual, and it goes against the IoC philosophy. However, I'd like to have something like Spring has done by the MethodInvokingFactoryBean. I'm thinking that I could implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly (not being very familiar with the MethodInvokingFactoryBean myself) what you need is a factory method, ie. something like the following:

```
   <bean id="myClass" class="foo.bar.MyClass" 
         factory-method="doSomething">   
       <argument ref="secondClass"/>    
   </bean>
```

You can find more details on how to use factories with blueprint [in this guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-osgiblueprint/) (one of the most useful blueprint resources IMO)

Comment: I was thinking something like that, but I'm afraid the factory-method doSomething() should be static, shouldn't be?

Comment: Yes, it should. Alternatively you can see if the instance factory method in the link I gave you is closer to your needs,

Comment: In the link it actually works as I was asking. The instance factory method invokes the method even if not static, on the instance you specify